# Make cancel button lower keyboard

Tags: iphone, sdk, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar. I enabled the 'cancel' button so it says cancel right next to the search box how can i set that button to simply lower the keyboard when the user presses it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this there's one delegate method called when cancel button is pressed

```
-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar
 {
      [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

-Happy Coding....